# images stored to mysql using android and using php

Tags: php, android

this is PHPScript i use to display on the browser images stored in mysql database.

```html
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = '$id' ";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane");
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
//echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
//echo base64_encode( $result['image'] );
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
//stripslashes ($result['image']);
echo ( $result['image'] );
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

in mysql database there is some images that i have stored using another Script php, and other images are stored using android application( by converting Bitmap to String and using StringBuilder ).

i can succefly display on the browser all images that have been stored by php Script, but i cannot disolay those who have been stored using android apps, i can just see a little rectangle oon the browser.

[image: display image, that have been stored in mysql using android apps]

can you clarify me what is going on ?

**php script that is responsable to add image to mysql database via android Application :**

```html
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane")or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)";
  
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
  
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  
  $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
  
  if($check == 1){
   echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
  }else{
   echo "Error Uploading Image";
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
  echo "Error";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you are simply assuming that your queries suceeded.  add basic debugging: `mysqli_whatever(...) or die(mysqli_error($con));` and DON'T output your `header()` until after you've confirmed that the queries worked. once you have that image header output, you won't see any debug output anymore, because the browser will try to read that error text as if it was an image (and fail).

Comment: but every thing works fine, except with some images that have been stored by android apps

Comment: then you should check that your apps are uploading the images correctly. maybe this php code is running properly, and you started garbage in the db.

Comment: i edit the post to show you php script i use with android studio to store image to database.

Answer (score 0):

yes i found it, to show in the browser all images that have been stored in mysql by an android apps, we have to use : `echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );` and for images that have been saved other way, we have to use just `echo ( $result['image'] );`